# Html form submission - button control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a HTML page which has two different forms.

After first form submission,user inputted information is saved and an SMS is sent.After that user continues to filling up the second form.

How can i control if the user clicks the second form's submit button ? How about a JavaScript alert ?

### Submit button div(2nd form):

```
<div class="button-container" style="float: right;">
    <button class="btn  type4  color2  ml228" type="submit" id="submitForm">
            Kaydol
    </button>
</div>
```

Please suggest/advice.

Comment: what do you mean by  "fullfilling first one"? @serkan

Comment: question is not much clear. do you want to stop user submitting the second form first?

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly submit 2 forms from one page unless you're doing an ajax call, or are just storing the data, without actually 'submitting it'.

If I understand you right, you just want to prevent the browser from submitting 2nd the form by default? And you want to check to make sure the first has already been submitted, when the second has been submitted?

```
firstFormSubmitted = 0;
secondFormSubmitted = 0;

//1st form
$('.firstForm').submit(function(){
    //do whatever you do to send an sms
    firstFormSubmitted = 1;
});

//2nd form
$('#submitForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!firstFormSubmitted){
        alert("First Form Must Be Submitted First!");
    }
    else {
          secondFormSubmitted = 1;
          // do whatever you want. Submit with ajax, submit normally, or whatever.
    }
});
```

basically you just have to prevent the browser from submitting it by default. and you want to check if the first form has been submitted. So on the first form you have to use a variable or a class or something to let your second form know that it has been submitted.

If you want to alert the user when they leave the page, that they haven't filled out the second form yet, you can use the unload function. Just use a boolean variable or something when the 2nd form has been submitted to let the browser know that it has been submitted.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    if(firstFormSubmitted && !secondFormSubmitted){
        alert( "You haven't filled out the second form yet!" );
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i have a control which you mentioned. what i want is: user fill up the first form and submit it. i have those infos.Than, he/she doesnt't continue with the second form and by browsers back or forward button, go to other page. so i want to make an alert if the user doesn't fill up the second form and submit it.